# Apache virtual host directory domain mapping clash

Tags: apache

By clash I mean that one domain works, it leads to `/var/www/html` and reads the main `index.php` file however the second domain which leads to `/var/www/html/website` gives me a permission denied for root directory "`/`" so I'm wondering if it is interpreting `/var/www/html` as `/`

Or is it something else?

Thank you for any help

Virtual host setup port 80 only

```
# works

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site.us
ServerAlias site.us http://www.site.us
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
# CustomLog /directory log file location not enabled
# ErrorLog /directory log not enabled
</VirtualHost>

# both site2.com and www.site2.com have 404 problem
# The requested URL / was not found on this server.

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAlias site2.com http://www.site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
# CustomLog /directory log file location not enabled
# ErrorLog /directory log not enabled
</VirtualHost>

# works fine

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site3.com
ServerAlias site3.com http://www.site3.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site3
# CustomLog /directory log file location not enabled
# ErrorLog /directory log not enabled
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Post your virtualhosts data, otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: That's the weird thing, it doesn't work for site 2, but site 3 works, so where is the difference?

Comment: I would never do what you're doing there. Every site should be in its own directory. Because of that I can't comment from experience. But try this: go to www.site.us/site2 and you should be in site2, same for site3/. Because this is something I'd literally never even think of trying, I can't say more on it from experience.

Comment: Isn't that domain mapping? And I thought they are in their own directories? I haven't rewritten the urls yet to only show site2 instead of www.site.us/site2

Comment: I think you need to provide more details as to why you selected this method over anything else, and what you actually want to happen, and why. I've never tried running separate sites from the same primary directory, nor can I understand why you'd want to do that.